# .. keyword meaning, can't find related help documents

Tags: elixir

Nx tutorial has the following sample code. What's the help document's of `1..4`?

[enter link description here](https://hexdocs.pm/nx/intro-to-nx.html#nx-and-tensors)

```
tensor =
  1..4
  |> Enum.chunk_every(2)
  |> Nx.tensor(names: [:y, :x])
```

At first, I think it is a list keyword. but I try try the following, and find not.

```
is_list(1..4) return false
```

Comment: Would it be possible to link to the tutorial?

Comment: I understand 1..4 means Enum, not list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem that it's a way of creating a [`Range`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Range.html).

The tutorial you [refer to](https://github.com/elixir-nx/nx/blob/main/nx/guides/intro-to-nx.livemd#creating-tensors) says the following:

> We use it to create tensors from raw Elixir **lists** of numbers

What is should have said was:

> We use it to create tensors from a `range` of numbers.

If you want `is_list()` to return `true`, you can explicitly convert it to a [`List`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html):

```
IO.puts is_list(Enum.to_list(1..4)) # Output: true
```

Comment: `[1..4]` is a list of length `1` containing the range itself. Using `Enum.to_list/1` as `Enum.to_list(1..4)` would be more appropriate here.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin - I don't know too much about `Elixir`, so I hesitated to go against the documentation and say `1..4` is a `list`. Feel free to edit my answer and I'll accept it. :D.